# How to convert prices in one dataframe with exchange rates in another one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe of amount bought like this:

```
import pandas as pd

amounts = pd.DataFrame({
    'symbol': ['EUR/USD', 'EUR/USD', 'GBP/USD', 'GBP/USD', 'EUR/GBP', 'EUR/GBP'],
    'time': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    'amount': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
})
amounts.set_index('symbol', inplace=True)

prices = pd.DataFrame({
        'symbol': ['EUR/USD', 'GBP/USD', 'EUR/GBP'],
        'price': [1.2, 1.5, 0.8]
})
prices.set_index('symbol', inplace=True)

amounts = amounts.join(prices, on='symbol')

amounts['eur'] = 0
amounts['eur'] = amounts['eur'].mask(
    amounts.index.str.split('/').str[0] == 'EUR', 
    amounts['amount'] / amounts['price'])

amounts['eur'] = amounts['eur'].mask(
    amounts.index.str.split('/').str[1] == 'EUR', 
    amounts['amount'] * amounts['price'])

amounts['eur'] = amounts['eur'].mask(
    (amounts['eur'] == 0) & (f'EUR/' + amounts.index.str.split('/').str[1]).isin(prices.index), 
    amounts['amount'] * amounts['price'] * 
    prices[f'EUR/' + amounts.index.str.split('/').str[1]])
```

The final output should be

```
amounts['eur'] = [
    0.83, # amount / price(EUR/USD) = 1 / 1.2
    0.83, # amount / price(EUR/USD) = 1 / 1.2
    2.5, # amount * price(GBP/USD) / price(EUR/USD) = 2 * 1.5 / 1.2
    2.5, # amount * price(GBP/USD) / price(EUR/USD) = 2 * 1.5 / 1.2 
    3.75, # amount / price(EUR/GBP) = 3 / 0.8
    3.75 # amount / price(EUR/GBP) = 3 / 0.8 
]
```

Everytime I try to have EUR as the denominator.

The last line raise an error unfortunately.

I would like to get the amount in EUr denomination.
Also, as I have millions of lines, I would like to avoid foor loops.

Any idea please?

Comment: Can you add your expected output ?

Comment: when you say last line doesn't work, what doesn't work since we don't know what you expect, we can't understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it with Pandas [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) method:

```py
# Setup
amounts = amounts.set_index("symbol")

# Convert all prices in EUR
prices["price_eur"] = prices["price"]
prices.loc[prices["symbol"] == "GBP/USD", "price_eur"] = (
    prices.loc[prices["symbol"] == "EUR/USD", "price"].values[0]
    / prices.loc[prices["symbol"] == "GBP/USD", "price"].values[0]
)
prices = prices.set_index("symbol")

# Add new column "eur"
amounts = (
    pd.merge(right=amounts, left=prices, how="right", right_index=True, left_index=True)
    .pipe(lambda df_: df_.assign(eur=df_["amount"] / df_["price_eur"]))
    .drop(columns="price_eur")
)
```

Then:

```py
         price  time  amount       eur
symbol
EUR/GBP    0.8     1       3  3.750000
EUR/GBP    0.8     2       3  3.750000
EUR/USD    1.2     1       1  0.833333
EUR/USD    1.2     2       1  0.833333
GBP/USD    1.5     1       2  2.500000
GBP/USD    1.5     2       2  2.500000
```